# Powershell script for setting Multi User Editing in excel for numerous files?

Tags: excel, powershell

I've written a code that tries to go through my company server and set all the excel files, under a certain folder, to shared so that multiple people can edit them at once.  This has been a problem for a very long time here and I thought I had a nice code to fix this but I can't seem to access the property correctly.  Can anyone help?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$root = "P:\A N G"

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $root -File "*.xlsx" -Recurse 

foreach ($excelFile in $excelFiles.FullName)
{
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelWorkBook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile) 

    if (!$excelWorkBook.MultiUserEditing)
    { 
        Write-Host   $excelFile     
        $excelWorkBook._SaveAs([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode]::xlShared)
        $excelWorkBook.Close
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that accelerated .NET method, `xlShared`, just a boolean? Also, after you call `Close()`, most PS/Excel code I've seen calls `.Quit()` after that as well. Are you able to open those Excel files from your machine? Or can you query the property on one of those Excel objects that you're trying to change after the code runs?

Comment: @trebleCode For future reference, type accelerators are a specific class in the powershell library which essentially aliases types and the term does not apply to every use of a .NET type (which is what is happening here).  Observe here: `[psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Get`  It's likely an enumeration that they're using

Comment: Cheers @TheIncorrigible1, your protips are always good!

Comment: @trebleCode glad to be of service.  You can also utilize that type's static member `Add` to define your own type accelerators (I use this functionality in my `$profile` for shortcuts)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 good to know, I can forsee making alot of use of that in the near future

Comment: @OP Do you mean you want to share the file through SMB?  Or some Excel-specific feature?

Comment: i forgot about the .Quit()  thank you trebleCode

Comment: Actually i probably want to add both $excelWorkBook.Quit() and 
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from a friend I managed to come up with a solution actually.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$root = "P:\A N G"

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $root -File "*.xlsx" -Recurse 

foreach ($excelFile in $excelFiles.FullName)
{
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelWorkBook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile) 

    if (!$excelWorkBook.MultiUserEditing)
    { 
        Write-Host $excelWorkBook.FullName   
        $accessMode = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode]::xlShared
        $xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
        $excelWorkBook.SaveAs($excelWorkBook.FullName,$xlFixedFormat,$null,$null,$null,$null,$accessMode,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null)
        $excelWorkBook.Close
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
```